# While installing Ubuntu 20.04 some package are being removed..will this cause any problems?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, hp, source-packages

I'm new for ubuntu.. while installing my ubuntu i first some package are installed...and then after some time lot of package being removed automatically.. will it cause any problem in performance?

Comment: Well, try it and let us know if you do encounter problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Ubuntu unneeded packages like packages for extra languages that you haven't selected during the installation of Ubuntu are automatically removed towards the end of the installation process, so that Ubuntu will not take too much space on the hard disk. The reason why removing unnecessary packages occurs towards the end of the installation process is in order to give the Ubuntu installer a chance to calculate the package requirements after drivers, third-party codecs and updates have been installed if these options were selected, so that the Ubuntu installer can check if there are any packages that are no longer needed and can be safely removed.